# C++ Quicksort error

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, quicksort

I'm trying to implement a quicksort algorithm but i keep getting the error "Invalid types 'double*[double]' for array subscript." for line 34 and 36 and "no matching function for call to Quicksort::QuickSort" for line 39
 Here is the code. Thank you.

```
double *QuickSort::Processor(double *Result, double *Array,int Size)
{

if (Size==0)
    return 0;
double *smallList, *largeList;
smallList=new double[Size];
largeList=new double[Size];

double pivot=Array[0];
int SmallNum, LargeNum=0;

for (int i=1;i<Size;i++)
{
    if(Array[i]<pivot)
        smallList[SmallNum++]=Array[i];
    else
        largeList[LargeNum++]=Array[i];
}
QuickSort (smallList,smallList,SmallNum);
QuickSort (largeList,largeList,LargeNum);
int num;

for(int i=0;i<SmallNum;i++)
    Result[num++]=smallList[i];

Result[num++]=pivot;
for(int i=0;i<LargeNum;i++)
    Result[num++]=largeList[i];
delete [smallList];
delete [largeList];
return Result;
}
```

Comment: I think we don't like to use raw pointers if we can avoid that. You get down votes because this is not the complete code for your quick sort. We can't compile the code you show. The code is hard to read without fixing the indentation. (i didn't down-vote)

Comment: There may be many problems with your code but won't be able to tell unless you post your whole code. At least the whole QuickSort class including the declaration. Based on what you post, QuickSort is a class that has a member method Processor. You have to call that member recursively, instead you call the QuickSort's constructor.

Comment: what is wrong with stackoverflow today? I don't see any references that aren't declared and the algorithm looks a lot like QuickSort algorithm to me. It should sort the results if the minor errors are fixed.

Comment: `delete [smallList];
delete [largeList];` quite unusual use of `delete[]`

Comment: @Garr And uninitialised variables, among other issues.

Comment: yes, num and SmallNum need to be initialized to 0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your question was downvoted. I see you've included a fair amount of code and your question is easy to understand and on topic.

Anyway, these lines:

```
delete [smallList];
delete [largeList];
```

should be

```
delete [] smallList;
delete [] largeList;
```

Your second problem is you are calling a function called `QuickSort`. Presumably that is supposed to be recursive call, but that isn't the name of your method. Your method is called `Processor`

Comment: "I'm not sure why your question was downvoted." Maybe it's only because the error is too obvious. Anyway, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Right, so i didn't downvote. Only in extreme situation should a post downvoted. But Stack Overflow cannot guarantee that all downvotes are reasonable. So I just guess why this question is downvoted. After all, it's only a 125 rep authority.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```
#include <iostream>

void copy(double* dest, const double* src, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) dest[i] = src[i];
}

double* quick_sort(double* dest, const double* src, const int size) {
    if (size == 0) return nullptr;

    double* left_array = new double[size];
    double* right_array = new double[size];

    double pivot = src[0];
    int left_size = 0;  // initialize this
    int right_size = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (src[i] < pivot) {
            left_array[left_size++] = src[i];
        } else {
            right_array[right_size++] = src[i];
        }
    }

    quick_sort(left_array, left_array, left_size);
    quick_sort(right_array, right_array, right_size);

    copy(dest, left_array, left_size);
    dest[left_size] = pivot;
    copy(dest + left_size + 1, right_array, right_size);

    delete[] left_array;
    delete[] right_array;
    return dest;
}

void print(const double arr[], const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    double src[20];
    double dest[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) src[i] = 7 * i % 16;
    quick_sort(dest, src, 20);
    print(dest, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0 0 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 14 15
```

Comment: Most of the time, we don't use new, delete, and pointers if we can avoid that by using `std::vector`. This code looks more like c than c++.